# Use ArcPy to add snapping guides to a layout in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts

I'm wondering if there is a way, ideally with Python, to add multiple snapping guides to a layout in ArcGIS Pro. Essentially, I want to reproduce something like the steps below:

1. Right click on the Ruler to bring up the "Add Guides" window:

[image]

2. Select the guide orientation, placement, and margin:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Pro's [Layout class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) has very few [Properties](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm#P_GUID-6DFB661B-D50A-4E3A-AE75-6884442AD100).

If you were able "to add multiple snapping guides to a layout in ArcGIS Pro" using ArcPy then I suspect that there would need to be a property that is a list of Guide objects.  ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro does not have a Guide class to create those Guide objects.

If this is important to you then you could post an [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the response!